# MySQL - get the sum of amount every month within a fiscal year

Tags: mysql

can someone teach me or help me to figure out how to display amount within a fiscal year?. The fiscal year I am using is November to October. So let say Fiscal Year 2016 is from November 2015 to October 2016.

Now my problem is I can only display the amount per month within the chosen year. How can I do this in mysql?

[image: This is my table:]

This is the query I have tried, but it works only within a year.

```
  select a.account, a.region, sum(n.amount) as 'Total Net',
  sum(case when n.savings_date between date_format(n.savings_date, '%Y-11-01')   and last_day(date_format(savings_date, '%Y-11-01')) then n.amount end) as `Nov`,
  sum(case when n.savings_date between date_format(n.savings_date, '%Y-12-01') and last_day(date_format(savings_date, '%Y-12-01')) then n.amount end) as `Dec`,
  sum(case when n.savings_date between date_format(n.savings_date, '%Y-01-01') and last_day(date_format(savings_date, '%Y-01-01')) then n.amount end) as `Jan`,
  sum(case when n.savings_date between date_format(n.savings_date, '%Y-02-01') and last_day(date_format(savings_date, '%Y-02-01')) then n.amount end) as `Feb`,
  sum(case when n.savings_date between date_format(n.savings_date, '%Y-03-01') and last_day(date_format(savings_date, '%Y-03-01')) then n.amount end) as `Mar`,
  sum(case when n.savings_date between date_format(n.savings_date, '%Y-04-01') and last_day(date_format(savings_date, '%Y-04-01')) then n.amount end) as `Apr`,
  sum(case when n.savings_date between date_format(n.savings_date, '%Y-05-01') and last_day(date_format(savings_date, '%Y-05-01')) then n.amount end) as `May`,
  sum(case when n.savings_date between date_format(n.savings_date, '%Y-06-01') and last_day(date_format(savings_date, '%Y-06-01')) then n.amount end) as `Jun`,
  sum(case when n.savings_date between date_format(n.savings_date, '%Y-07-01') and last_day(date_format(savings_date, '%Y-07-01')) then n.amount end) as `Jul`,
  sum(case when n.savings_date between date_format(n.savings_date, '%Y-08-01') and last_day(date_format(savings_date, '%Y-08-01')) then n.amount end) as `Aug`,
  sum(case when n.savings_date between date_format(n.savings_date, '%Y-09-01') and last_day(date_format(savings_date, '%Y-09-01')) then n.amount end) as `Sep`,
  sum(case when n.savings_date between date_format(n.savings_date, '%Y-10-01')      and last_day(date_format(savings_date, '%Y-10-01')) then n.amount end) as `Oct`
   from 
   net_savings n left join accounts a
   on a.id = n.account_id
   where year(n.savings_date) = '2016'
   group by a.account
   order by a.account desc
```

I am needing this kind of output also:

[image]

Appreciate your answers or suggestions! :)

Comment: It's generally best to handle issues of data display in a presentation layer/application level code - assuming that's available

Comment: We can't do that in application level or presentation leyer.

Comment: In which case see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    a.account,
    a.region,
    YEAR(n.savings_date),
    MONTH(n.savings_date),
    SUM(n.amount)
FROM
    net_savings n
LEFT JOIN
    accounts a
ON
    a.id = n.account_id
WHERE
    n.savings_date >= '2015-11-01' and n.savings_date < '2016-09-01'
GROUP BY
    a.account,
    a.region,
    YEAR(n.savings_date),
    MONTH(n.savings_date),
ORDER BY
    a.account DESC
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I'm looking for. I need the months to be in treated as columns not rows. Thanks anyway. And my input should only be a year for example 2016